# 0xc00000e9 Windows Error and dual boot - can bootrepair, grub or Linux fdisk repair this?

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, grub

I get a `0xc00000e9` error when I try to boot Windows 10 of my dual boot system. See picture below.

I read many posts on this error, but they all feature Windows-based solutions - using a Win 10 install disk or stick.

However, I dread using a Windows-based solution, I fear it may corrupt GRUB, MBR, etc.

**So, I wonder if I can repair my system boot using [bootrepair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) or GRUB, or any other Linux-based solution?**

Some notes:

1. Linux (Mint 20) boots without a hiccup.
2. The system does read the Windows partition and Windows files. I can explore Windows folders and files. The UEFI / BIOS recognise the files and folders. See pic below. It is unlikely there is an issue with the cables or hardware.
3. I disabled CSM support, (even though the picture below shows otherwise, I changed this setting).
4. `Fdisk` output is shown below.

--

[image]

[image]

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 96.52 MiB, 101191680 bytes, 197640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 96.101 MiB, 101695488 bytes, 198624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB          
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048    999423    997376   487M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    999424   1032191     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3   3096576 576774143 573677568 273.6G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 576774144 976771071 399996928 190.8G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048 1945137151 1945135104 927.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  1945137152 1953523711    8386560     4G Linux swap

Disk /dev/sdb: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048  102402047  102400000  48.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       102402048 1953523711 1851121664 882.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20SPZX-00U
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 3907028991 3907026944  1.8T 83 Linux
    
Disk /dev/sdd: 29.53 GiB, 31691112448 bytes, 61896704 sectors
Disk model: SD              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        8192 61896703 61888512 29.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: I doubt you are going to pull this off.  You will probably need to repair windows boot.. then boot from a Linux Live disk and then fix GRUB.  Also.. I have seen this error many times.. in my experience it is either drive corruption or a problem with the disk itself.  Have you scanned the disk for errors?  Linux booting means nothing.

Comment: Will give it a go - I realized the disk is an M.2 drive (not SATA) mounted on the motherboard.